# How to place a panel containing three buttons in the upper left cell of a GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, swing

I have a panel that contains three buttons. I want this panel to be placed in the upper left cell of a `GridBagLayout`.

My problem is that when I run the program the panel is not located in the upper left cell but it's in the middle of the layout. I have set both `gridx`and `gridy` to zero.

```
private JFrame frame;

private JMenuBar menuBar;
private JMenu menuFile;
private JMenuItem fileItem1;
private JMenuItem fileItem2;

private JPanel btnPanel;
private JButton btnRewind;
private JButton btnPlayPause;
private JButton btnFastForward;

private static boolean shouldFill = true;
private static boolean shouldWeightX = true;
private static boolean RIGHT_TO_LEFT = false;

public JPlayer() {

}

public void createAndShowGUI() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("JPlayer");
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    addComponentsToPane(frame.getContentPane());

    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) {
    if(RIGHT_TO_LEFT) {
        pane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
    }

    pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    if(shouldFill) {
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    }

    btnRewind = new JButton();
    try {
        Image imgRewind = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("../utils/images/rewind.png"));

        btnRewind.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imgRewind));
        btnRewind.setOpaque(true);
        btnRewind.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btnRewind.setBorderPainted(false);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    btnPlayPause = new JButton();
    try {
        Image imgPlay = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("../utils/images/play.png"));
        Image imgPause = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("../utils/images/pause.png"));

        btnPlayPause.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imgPlay));
        btnPlayPause.setOpaque(true);
        btnPlayPause.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btnPlayPause.setBorderPainted(false);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    btnFastForward = new JButton();
    try {
        Image imgFastForward = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("../utils/images/fast_forward.png"));

        btnFastForward.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imgFastForward));
        btnFastForward.setOpaque(true);
        btnFastForward.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        btnFastForward.setBorderPainted(false);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    btnPanel = new JPanel();
    btnPanel.add(btnRewind);
    btnPanel.add(btnPlayPause);
    btnPanel.add(btnFastForward);
    btnPanel.setSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;

    JButton btn = new JButton("Some Button");
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;

    pane.add(btnPanel, gbc);
    pane.add(btn, c);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [GridBagConstraints.anchor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#anchor) constraint that has default value as CENTER positioned.

Directly from documentation on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

> If a component's display area is larger than the component itself, then you can specify whereabouts in the display area the component will be displayed by using the `GridBagConstraints.anchor` constraint.
>
> The **anchor** constraint's values can be absolute (north, south, east, west, and so on), or **orientation-relative** (at start of page, at end of line, at the start of the first line, and so on), or relative to the component's baseline.

[image]

**Note**:

1. You don't need to use multiple instances of *GridBagConstraints*. Just create one and update the constraints before adding the component in the panel. In this way you can reuse the existing constraints that is common for all.
2. Don't forget to set `weightx` and `weighty` to use `anchor` constraints properly.

Directly from same documentation

**weightx, weighty**

> Specifying weights is an art that can have a significant impact on the appearance of the components a GridBagLayout controls. Weights are used to determine how to distribute space among columns (weightx) and among rows (weighty); this is important for specifying resizing behavior.
>
> Unless you specify at least one non-zero value for *weightx* or *weighty*, **all the components clump together in the center of their container**. This is because when the weight is 0.0 (the default), the GridBagLayout puts any extra space between its grid of cells and the edges of the container.